# how to get the name of each folder inside a certain folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-formatting

I'm writing a bash script that needs to list all the names of folders inside a certain folder and print their description from a file inside each folder. here is a example filesystem:

```
main
||
\/
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
template
```

inside each folder other than `main` there is a file called `description` (including the `template` folder), here is an example description file:

```
folder1
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z
```

**the folders might change name, more be added, and some removed. so I don't want to hardcode any number or name**

I want to print all the folders and their descriptions like this using only bash and as little if any other programs (cat, grep etc. is ok) and **without** the `template` folder:

```bsh
**folder1**
folder1
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z

**folder2**
folder2
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z

**folder3**
folder3
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z

**folder4**
folder4
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z
```

**^note that the template folder isn't in my example output of what I want**

so far I have this code:

```bsh
function list-all() {
  folderlist=()
  for file in /home/USER/main/*; do
      echo "$(basename "$file")"
  done
}
```

it prints all the folder names in a vertical list like this:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
template
```

from this output I want to get to this:

```
folder1
folder1
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z

folder2
folder2
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z

folder3
folder3
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z

folder4
folder4
=======
contains:
* x
* y
* z
```

thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you simply mean `cat main/*/description`?

Comment: @terdon I also want the folder name and I want to omit the `template` folder. see my example output.

Comment: According to the question, the folder name is in the description file, and the description file does not contain the description of `template`. Of course, you might argue that `cat` is not Bash.

Comment: @NasirRiley I edited my question and added what I tried.

Comment: @berndbausch thats not what I mean. I edited my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you are going for is something like this:

```
for dir in /home/USER/main/*/; do
    dirname=$(basename "$dir")
    if [[ "$dirname" != "template" ]]; then        
        echo "$dirname"
        cat "$dir"/description
    fi
done
```